# Creating multiple directories in documents folder for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, directory, nsdocumentdirectory

I want to make multiple directories I do not know how. This is my code up till now .

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tops",@"bottoms",@"right" ];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil]; //Create folder

}
```

I want to have 4 directories that are named tops bottoms right and left however it does not work if I do it in the above way.. Is there a way to make multiple directories using this code? or is my code wrong? Thanks!

Comment: you need to iterate four times to create 4 directories

Comment: Hmm .. [this exact question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055646/creating-multiple-directory-in-documents) was asked by another user some time ago(was downvoted and put **on hold**). And your profile is created just minutes ago! I am suspicious.

Comment: @Amar You are right. It looks like the same one.

Comment: It is still a useful question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this code.

To create directories as you asked.

```
NSArray *directoryNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"tops",@"bottoms",@"right",@"left",nil];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder

for (int i = 0; i < [directoryNames count] ; i++) {
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[directoryNames objectAtIndex:i]];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil]; //Create folder
}
```

To use your created directories anywhere in your app.

```
NSArray *directoryNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"tops",@"bottoms",@"right",@"left",nil];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder

// This will return the folder name in the 0 position. In yours "tops"
NSString *topDirPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[directoryNames objectAtIndex:0]];
// This will return the file path in your "tops" folder
NSString *filePath = [topDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MYIMAGE"];
```

To store an image file

```
NSData *imageDataToStore = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[imageDataToStore writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

To retrieve an image file

```
// Convert the file into data and then into image.
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
UIImage *yourImage =  [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: Im getting errors saying use of undeclared identifier "i" and how should I recall the directory so that I can save pictures in..

Comment: sorry I have written code in answer box in SO. so only. Now I have declared `i` in `for` loop. Check it now.

Comment: Lastly one more question how do you recall the directory so that I can save photos in the directory that I created..

Comment: @AppleDevram I am writing a code for you. And you are simply playing with adding / removing the tick button in my answer.

Comment: @AppleDevram Still I am writing code for you. If you want to finish your task , then WAIT. If you want fast answer, then ask another question to recall the folder.

Comment: So to store an image file where am I suppose to declare the directory name?(I will be using a UIPickerView) I have the camera code written in my app and want to make the user select which directory to save. Its like a gallery app.

Comment: You just need to declare the directory name in which method you are storing an image file. That would be fine.